# How to properly construct a sentence with "experimenting (with)"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm not sure how to construct my sentence properly with the word "experimenting":

> I'm still experimenting **(with)** how to draw humans.

Among the examples I could find I often saw the structure "experimenting with **verb + -ing**", but I don't know if saying the following would be correct either:

> I'm still experimenting with drawing humans.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both versions are correct, and both versions require the "with".

Comment: @CanadianYankee Maybe you could write it as an answer? It actually helped me, thank you. :)